# How to solve "windows resource protection could not run" when using sfc /scannow

Tags: windows-10

When using *sfc /scannow* on my Windows 10 Pro 64bit system I am geting error "windows resource protection could not run the requested operation"

This is from the CBS log:

> 2017-02-01 10:29:29, Info                  CBS    TiWorker: Client
>   requests SFP repair object. 2017-02-01 10:29:29, Info
>   CSI    00000002@2017/2/1:09:29:29.390 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version
>   0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7ffc037d8889 @0x7ffc24f14fe5 @0x7ffc24f15132 @0x7ff7fc7e244d @0x7ff7fc7e3c97 @0x7ffc2f22b0b3) 2017-02-01 10:29:29,
>   Info                  CBS    Failed to load the COMPONENTS hive from
>   'C:\WINDOWS\System32\config\COMPONENTS' into registry key
>   'HKLM\COMPONENTS'. [HRESULT = 0x80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED] 2017-02-01
>   10:29:29, Info                  CBS    Failed to load component store
>   [HRESULT = 0x80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED] 2017-02-01 10:29:29, Info
>   CSI    00000003 GetSystemStore called without loading components hive
>   2017-02-01 10:29:29, Error                 CSI
>   00000004@2017/2/1:09:29:29.492 (F)
>   base\wcp\componentstore\com\store.cpp(5791): Error
>   HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) originated in function
>   CreateOrGetIStore expression: (null) [gle=0x80004005] 2017-02-01
>   10:29:29, Info                  CBS    Added
>   C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CBS.log to WER report. 2017-02-01 10:29:29, Info
>   CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20170122132059.cab to WER
>   report. 2017-02-01 10:29:29, Info                  CBS    Added
>   C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20170121231147.cab to WER report.
>   2017-02-01 10:29:29, Info                  CBS    Added
>   C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20170121205257.cab to WER report.
>   2017-02-01 10:29:29, Info                  CBS    Added
>   C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20170118072131.cab to WER report.
>   2017-02-01 10:29:29, Info                  CBS    Added
>   C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20161223125107.cab to WER report.
>   2017-02-01 10:29:29, Info                  CBS    Could not get active
>   session for current session file logging [HRESULT = 0x80004003 -
>   E_POINTER] 2017-02-01 10:29:29, Info                  CBS    Not able
>   to add pending.xml to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 -
>   ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND] 2017-02-01 10:29:29, Info                  CBS
>   Not able to add pending.xml.bad to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT =
>   0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]

It should be said I am trying to solve this because I also have troubles installing e.g. Visual Studio redistributables - I was then recommended trying to see system otherwise checked out allright....

Comment: this can happen if you use a 32bit cmd.exe on a 64 bit windows and if you have disabled the windows module installer (trustedinstaller) service

Comment: You should be using DISM not SFC to fix corruption issues in Windows 10.

Comment: Okay - after a lot of sfc, dsim, failed chkdsk, blue screens with ntfs errors, removing los of anivurs and other files I finally got a stable system where I could aslo upgrade to latest Windows 10 as well - thank you everyone